# using outside smtp to deliver cron generated emails

Tags: cron

I want to deliver cron generated emails to my id, abc@example.com instead of being saved on /var/spool/clientqueue

I've done the following:

echo "set smtp=smtp.example.com" > /root/.mailrc
echo "set from=abc@exmaple.com" >> /root/.mailrc

but nothing happen.

Any help ??

No I don't want to run MTA on my machine. I want to using external smtp instead of running a smtp on my machine. this is what i want.

I don't want to use postfix or sendmail. I want to use a smtp server as normally we use smtp in outlook express as outgoing server. Same like that i want to use an external smtp for cron.

I want to deliver emails on behalf of other MTA which would be use as smtp for all of the emails delivery.

Comment: Do you actually have an MTA running on the box? Which one? And can you post the content of /etc/aliases.

Comment: Without an MTA how do you expect the machine to be able to pass that email to another server?